# Sync data from iOS app to core data in OS X app

Tags: ios, macos, swift, web-services, core-data

I have an iOS app which multiple users will install. I want to gather the data coming from multiple users from iOS app into my OS X app.  Can someone tell me what is the best possible way to achieve this? I can use a web service here but would like to transfer the gathered data from web service to Core Data in my OS X app. I am coding in swift.

Answer (score 0):

How about iCloud?

Try these links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html

http://www.objc.io/issues/10-syncing-data/icloud-core-data/